# What constitutes "Account Activity" in a debt collection timeline?

Tags: credit-report, credit-history, debt-collection

Let's say a person has a debt that charged off several years ago. They receive a time boxed, partial amount payoff offer from a Credit Agency that purchased the debt from the original lender. Do they have to respond to the offer, or contact the Credit Agency in order to create an Account Activity that will update last date of account activity that the 7 year window that the Credit Reporting agencies use. Or, does the action on the part of the Agency alone constitute "Account Activity"?

Answer (score 3):

Giving them money is account activity.  If contacting you was account activity any debtor could extend the timeline infinitely by simply contacting you every so often.

Comment: I've been told account activity can be less than that, that even trying to negotiate with them can be activity. Do you have any additional info to support it's only paying money that extends the 7 year period?